# why neo4j indexing can't find the nodes which I know they exist?

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have created and indexed my graph database through localhost:7474 in neo4j(visually).

The Nodes have three properties,name,priority,link.

and I created index on name property of nodes through

> add or remove indexes

tab of localhost:7474(as shown in picture)[image]

but when I try to retrieve nodes based on their names,in data browser,console,or my java application the nodes can not be found.

in console or data browser,when I write this query for red(there is a node with the name of red),for example:

```
start n=node:name(name="red")
return n;
```

I get `returned 0 rows`.

and when I type this query:

```
start n=node:node(name="red")
return n;
```

or this one:

```
start n=node:Node(name="red")
return n;
```

I get `Index`node`does not exist`,`Index`Node`does not exist`,in console or data browser.

my database file is in the same path which neo4j default.graphdb file exists(I mean in "C:\Users\fereshteh\Documents\Neo4j" ),and I first created the index,and then the graph database.

I don't know what I am doing wrong,please help me,I will be so thankful.

version of neo4j:1.9.4

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: what should I do Nicholas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your assumption about how to set up the indexing is incorrect. You can read [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.4/indexing.html) for more information, but basically there are 3 things that are needed to create/read from an index. The Index name, the entry key, and the entry value.

What you have specified above in the Web Console is the Index name, but in your cypher query, you are specifying the entry key. You either want to use the [Node Auto index](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.4/auto-indexing.html), or to create a node in cypher and index it there but that isn't an option in 1.9.4.

Comment: my Index name and the entry key are the same(both "name")(entry key is one of node properties which is name),they should not be the same?is this the problem?I did not get my answer,what should I do?you mean I should first pass nodes to my index and then search them,I should do this by Node Auto index?you mean just identifying an index in localhost is not enough?I myself should determine for example this index will be for these 10 nodes(by Auto index,or cypher,or in my java program)?and then I search from those ten nodes?I am new to neo4j,could you tell me what is the problem completely,please?

Comment: The link which you gave me above is about making an index through java api(I saw it before),how should I handle indexing through localhost:7474?

Comment: You can't unless you use the auto index. The Web Console doesn't have a way, nor does cypher for the version you are using. The only way is either using the Java API, or the REST api.

Comment: so there are three ways of indexing:1.Auto index,2.java api,3.rest api,am I right?I should follow one of these three methods?so what is that tab in localhost:7474?you know neo4j is really poor in documentation,explains about the approaches but does not give a complete schema of what is going on.

Comment: Yes, the tab in the web console is just to show/create them, but it doesn't offer much.

Comment: I've been using the REST Api adding nodes to indexes as part of a batch.  It seems to work really well.

Comment: Remotely it's the only way. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if you believe it to be the best answer.